# Compose a query with delay

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive

How can I compose the following query such that, I want the student to repeat the task if he fails, but his next retry must be with some delay.

1. DoSomeTask
2. If failed then wait 5 minutes and try again.
3. Show the result.

**Code part:**

```
student.DoSomeTask()
       .Repeat()
       .SkipWhile(r => r.Succeeded == false);
```

Comment: Are you sure doing this in a query makes sense?  It seems that having a timestamp field on the database and examining that BEFORE executing the query makes far more sense

Comment: This is something like sending some data over socket to a server and depending on the result received retrying the same task again but with a delay.

Comment: That logic should be handled in your code initializing the request, NOT the query itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
student.DoSomeTask()
    .SelectMany(r=>r.Succeeded 
        ? Observable.Empty<long>() 
        : Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)).Concat(Observable.Throw<long>(new ExamFailedException())).IgnoreElements())
    .Retry()
```

(Note the above code has not been tested)

If the student passes, then complete, else wait 5min then throw
If exception, retry.

Answer (score 0):

I made a new DelayWhile method with a delay parameter which delays the failed result.

```
public static IObservable<TSource> DelayWhile<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate, TimeSpan dueTime)
{
    return Observable.Create<TSource>(
        o => source
                    .Subscribe(value =>
                                {
                                    bool running;

                                    try
                                    {
                                        running = !predicate(value);
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        o.OnError(ex);

                                        return;
                                    }

                                    if (!running)
                                    {
                                        Thread.Sleep(dueTime);

                                        return;
                                    }

                                    o.OnNext(value);
                                },
                            o.OnError,
                            o.OnCompleted));
}
```

The new query is:

```
student.DoSomeTask()
       .Repeat()
       .SkipWhile(r => r.Succeeded == false, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```